# updating per category in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
id | ImportDate | ExpirationDate
1   | 2014-08-21 | 2014-08-21
1   | 2014-08-19 | 2014-08-20
2   | 2014-08-20 | 2014-08-20
2   | 2014-08-19 | 2014-08-19
```

Now I want to update only those rows which have max(importDate) and set theme ExpirationDate to 9999-12-31. So rows 1 and 3. The code is:

```
update table
set ExpirationDate = '9999-12-31'
Where 
ImportDate = (SELECT MAX(ImportDate) FROM table 
 group by id
)
```

but I got an error 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'
I seems strage for me bacause SELECT in Subquery is suppose to return only one date per id. Any ideas how to achive this update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems self-explanatory.  To fix it, you can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
update t
    set ExpirationDate = '9999-12-31'
    from table t
    Where ImportDate = (SELECT MAX(ImportDate)
                        FROM table t2
                        WHERE t2.id = t.id
                       )
```

Comment: I can't place alias with update statment. However this:     update table 
    set ExpirationDate = '9999-12-31'
    Where ImportDate = (SELECT MAX(ImportDate)
                        FROM table t2
                        WHERE t2.id = id
                       ); produces the same error.

Comment: I've found that in t-sql an update with alias is a bit tricky. The code which works should be like this: update t1
    set t1.ExpirationDate = '9999-12-31' from table t1
    Where t1.ImportDate = (SELECT MAX(ImportDate)
                        FROM table t2
                        WHERE t2.id = t1.id
                       );

Comment: @arth81 . . . You can use an alias.  It just has to be defined in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Another style that I prefer (as it's more readable to me)

```
with cte as (
   select *
      , row_number() over (
          partition by [id] 
          order by [ImportDate] desc
      ) as [r]
   from dbo.Table
)
update cte
set ImportDate = '9999-12-31'
where [r] = 1
```